# Are you allowed to "copy" the GUI/Features of another application

Tags: java, legal, copyright, software

I'm making a app which is based heavily on another application that serves a similar purpose. I'm not actually planning on selling it, but I'm wondering whether it would even be legal for me to sell it.

I don't borrow graphics from the other application, but I have a very similar color scheme, virtually the same features (I added a few, but not really significant), and a very similar interface layout. Obviously, I'm not borrowing any code (It's written in Objective-C and mines written in Java).

Again, I'm not actually planning on selling it, I was just wondering in the hypothetical. I'm not sure whether it's just the code that's copyrighted or the actually design itself.

Comment: Consider [Zynga copying Triple Town with Yeti Town](http://popwatch.ew.com/2012/02/03/triple-town-david-edery-cloning/) and the [associated ruling](http://www.forbes.com/sites/ericgoldman/2012/09/27/recent-ruling-in-triple-townyeti-town-game-app-dispute-provides-cautionary-lessons-for-both-ea-and-zynga/) - of course, the best thing to do is talk to a lawyer versed in IP law.

Comment: My brother is an IP lawyer. Whenever I ask him a question like this, he tells me that his answer will depend on who is paying him. Prostitutes, all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: True, I always kind feel that way as well. Obviously, the fact that in the US there's a "case law" approach could feel reassuring in this regard; but as long as a case hasn't reached state or federal... you can't know for sure! And it does feel like this could be a lottery if things go down "let's decide this in court" way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As usual: [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL), but I'd say that...

**Yes: you can copy UI elements and color-schemes**

### Elements of UI Design are NOT Generally Viewed as IP

While You can patent functionalities and behaviors, you **cannot** patent or copyright or trademark a design, **except if it's the design of a brand or logo for a registered trademark**. Similarly, you can't copyright a color charter: it's too generic.

However, you can patent GUI-related functionalities, unfortunately, because the patent system is clueless (in the US and some other countries). e.g., double-clicking, swiping, and things like that...

In the case of a complete clone, as far as I know (which isn't much, let's make that clear again), this could be ground for legal issues. Meaning if you'd have copied the screen's content, mode of navigation AND color schemes, some people would find it legitimate to sue you. **Doesn't mean they would succeed, but that could a risk.** They'd be unlikely to succeed as they can't own the IP for the design, and you'd have re-implemented it entirely.

For additional confirmation and what it's worth:

- OnStartups answer on *"[is it legal to copy a user interface?](http://www.brightjourney.com/q/legal-copy-user-interface)"*
- *"[Why the look and Feel of Software User Interfaces Should not be Protected by Copyright Law](http://www.foo.be/andria/docs/p563-samuelson.pdf)"* by Pamela Samuelson

### Counter Point

However, note that there's literature covering the other hangle as well, such as the *["Appendix L - What Can You Borrow"](http://hcibib.org/tcuid/appx-l.html)* to *["Task-Centered User Interface Design"](http://hcibib.org/tcuid/)*:

> - Things you can probably not copy -- again, watch the news and check with your attorney.
>
>   - Sequences or arrangements of menu items, commands, screens, etc., if you're only copying the sequence order because it will make it easier for users of someone else's existing program to use your new program.
>   - Icons, commands, menu items, or other words that are not an obvious choice to describe their function, even if they would make your program more usable for users of the original program. An example might be a database print command labelled "DataDump," or a mouse-options icon showing a cute little mouse with a checklist.
> - Things you can certainly not copy (unless you get permission).
>
>   - Things you've written earlier for a different company.
>   - An entire interface from another company's program, even if you implement it with all new code.
>   - An entire detailed screen from another company's program.
>       [...]
>   - Trademarks from other companies. If you need to use someone else's trademark, such as "Unix" in documentation, be sure you credit the owner: "Unix is a trademark of Unix Systems Laboratories, Inc."
>   - Patented features. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to discover what's patented.
>   - Exact bitmaps of icons, words, or fonts.
>   - Graphic details that define an interface's aesthetic look.

Note that:

- this leaves room for interpretation,
- this isn't legal advice either.

### Bottom Line? Get a Lawyer... or Don't Copy!!!

Comment: Incidentally, [Lotus vs. Borland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Development_Corp._v._Borland_International,_Inc.) found that copying a menu structure for compatibility was allowed.

Comment: There is a corner case. If your intention was to confuse a buyer so he would mistake your product for the original product (because of color scheme, font, similar logos etc. ) then you could be sued.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: you probably missed this paragraph in my answer, which already mentions this corner case: `In the case of a complete clone, as far as I know (which isn't much, let's make that clear again), this could be ground for legal issues. Meaning if you'd have copied the screen's content, mode of navigation AND color schemes, some people would find it legitimate to sue you. Doesn't mean they would succeed, but that could a risk. They'd be unlikely to succeed as they can't own the IP for the design, and you'd have re-implemented it entirely.`

Comment: @JamesAnderson: It's also in the quote I give a bit further down in the answer, amongst "things you can certainly NOT copy: `An entire interface from another company's program, even if you implement it with all new code.` and `Graphic details that define an interface's aesthetic look.` But, as I mention in my answer, whether this would be admissible in court is a different thing, and is difficult to define.

Comment: Looks at ACDSee and CamtasiaStudio. Very hard to tell them apart! It's not hyberbolic, just have a look at both. In that situation, ASCDsee copied CamtasiaStudio. No suing ensued. (yes, had to write that alliteration)

Answer (score 0):

Well twitter has a patent on the [pull to refresh functionality](http://www.theverge.com/2013/5/21/4350826/twitter-pull-to-refresh-patent-innovators-patent-agreement-announced) so in theory you could get sued if you chose to copy that feature. That is just one example. There are tons of software patents out there, so no. You can't always copy a feature.